# How to print string elements from an array vertically?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array and I want to print every element vertically.
For example:

```
myArr = ['abc', 'def','ghi'];
```

the output should be:

a d g

b e h

c f i

I've managed to do that in php by using 2 for loops but I'm having trouble with the same task in JS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your JS code so far and tell us where you're stuck. We're not going to just write it for you.

Comment: console.log(myArr[0]);console.log(myArr[1]);console.log(myArr[2]);

Comment: When you say "print" do you mean display on a webpage or write to the console?

Comment: displaying in a textarea

Comment: Post your javascript code.. what have you done, what is not working and what it should do?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62659930/print-words-vertically-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution, with two loops. Then you can just drop it inside some textarea or whatever you like.

```js
const myArr = ['abc', 'def','ghi'];
const r = myArr.map((elem, i) => elem.split('').map((_, a) => myArr[a][i]).join(' ')).join('\n');
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which takes an iterable and in this case it splits a sting into sinlge chracters and enables to use a mapping function for further processing, which is necessary here to transpose the strings.

```js
var array = ['abc', 'def','ghi'],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, s, j) => Array.from(s, (c, i) => (r[i] || '') + c), [])
        .join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like that:

```js
myArr = ['abc', 'def','ghi'];

myArr.forEach((element)=>{
 console.log(element);
})
```

Comment: He wants it printed vertically by char.

Comment: I guess you misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can break them as individual elements (as in ["a","b","c","d"...]) in an array and then transpose the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ary = ['abc', 'def','ghi'];
for (i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    const x = ary.map((ary) => ary[i]).join('')
    console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this**

```js
let myArr = ['abc', 'def','ghi'];
let op = new Array(myArr.length).fill('')

for(let i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<myArr[i].length;j++){
    op[j] += myArr[i][j]+' ';
  }
}
let finalOp = op.reduce((op,cur)=>{
  return op+=cur+`\n`;
},'')
console.log(finalOp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this JS function it can help you, you need to split each word of the array element:

```
function printArraySplitedLines(collection){
  collection.forEach(function(elementCollection) {
    let line = "";
    elementCollection.split('').forEach(function(item) {
        line += `${item} `;
    })
    console.log(line);
  });
}

printArraySplitedLines(myArr);

// a b c 
// d e f 
// g h i
```