# Print Words Vertically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement this algorithm in Javascript.

Given a string s. Return all the words vertically in the same order in which they appear in s.
Words are returned as a list of strings, complete with spaces when is necessary. (Trailing spaces are not allowed).
Each word would be put on only one column and that in one column there will be only one word.

```
Input: s = "TO BE OR NOT TO BE"
Output: ["TBONTB","OEROOE","   T"]
Explanation: Trailing spaces is not allowed. 
"TBONTB"
"OEROOE"
"   T"
```

My solution:

```
var printVertically = function(s) {
    let ans = [];
    if(s === null || s.length === 0)
        return ans;
    
    let arr = s.split(" ");
    let biggest = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i].length > biggest)
            biggest = arr[i].length;
    }
    
    let getBigWord = false;
    while(arr.length !== 0) {
        let word = arr.shift().split("");
        if(!getBigWord && word.length === biggest)
            getBigWord = true;
        for(i=0; i<biggest; i++){
            if(ans.length <= i)
                ans[i] = word[i] === undefined ? " " : word[i];
            else if(word[i] !== undefined) {
                ans[i] += word[i];
            } else if(!getBigWord) {
                ans[i] += " ";
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ans;
};
```

For the input above, it works. However, if I change the input the solutions doesn't work. For example:

```
Input: s = "CONTEST IS COMING"
Output: ["CIC","OSO","N M","T I","E N","S G","T"]
```

My output will be: ["CIC","OSO","NM","TI","EN","SG","T"]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What were your findings? And what about you simply remove spaces from the output you got in the second example? That shouldn't be too difficult...

Comment: "Trailing spaces are not allowed"

Comment: Please define then. I see no *trailing space*.

Comment: For those who are wondering, this is from Leetcode as [Print Words Vertically](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-words-vertically/description/).

Comment: @ggorlen yeah I had that feeling...

Comment: OP pleas read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Related threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53785418/how-to-print-string-elements-from-an-array-vertically), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59241745/i-want-to-print-an-array-of-strings-in-vertical-order-const-myarr-google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is a series of simple operations:

1. Split the string into words.
2. Create a matrix (2d array). The longest word in the string is the height (row count) of the matrix and the length of the number of strings is the width (column count).
3. Put the words in the string into the array rotated, that is, swap `i` and `j`s where `i` is the row and `j` is the column.
4. Join and trim the right side of each row.

```js
const verticize = s => {
  const words = s.split(/\s+/);
  return [...Array(Math.max(...words.map(e => e.length)))]
    .map((_, i) => 
      [...Array(words.length)]
        .map((_, j) => words[j][i] || " ").join("").trimEnd());
};

console.log(verticize("CONTEST IS COMING"));
```

Comment: It says "Trailing spaces are not allowed"

Comment: I don't see any trailing spaces. Can you show the output it's failing on? Are you sure you've posted the correct, complete specification?

Comment: I thought the description says can't use trim() functions

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in your post. I don't think you're giving us the fully story here. It's trivial to write your own `trimEnd` function in any case: `const trimEnd = s => s.replace(/\s*$/, "")`, so just plop that in place of the `trimEnd` call....

Comment: *can't use trim() functions* - if you are asking people to do your homework then please be clear about it and we'll make sure to close your question. Otherwise this solution is perfectly fine and provides the correct output for the "expected output" you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You're never resetting the value of getBigWord so it's not working properly once you've seen a big word. Also it does not look like it would work properly for multiple big words.

This seems to work better:

```
var printVertically = function(s) {
  let ans = [];
  if(s === null || s.length === 0)
    return ans;

  let arr = s.split(" ");
  let biggest = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].length > biggest)
      biggest = arr[i].length;
  }

  while(arr.length !== 0) {
    let word = arr.shift().split("");
    let getBigWord = false
    if(word.length === biggest) {
      getBigWord = true;
    }
    for(i=0; i<biggest; i++){
      if(ans.length <= i)
        ans[i] = word[i] === undefined ? " " : word[i];
      else if(word[i] !== undefined) {
        ans[i] += word[i];
      } else if(!getBigWord) {
        ans[i] += " ";
      }
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i < ans.length; i++) {
    // Modern version :
    // ans[i] = ans[i].trimRight(); 
    ans[i] = ans[i].replace(/\s+$/g, "");
  }

  return ans;
};
```

I need to trim at the end to avoid extra spaces

Comment: It says: "Trailing spaces are not allowed"

Comment: Review your definition of *trailing space* before telling everyone they didn't understand it.